# Converting JSON not returning Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON returning from my server that looks like this

```
[{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"},{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"},{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"}]
```

I then handle this by using

```
var data =  JSON.parse(json);
```

then, once doing this, I call this in a loop

```
data.item(i);
```

or using the function
    data.splice(i, 1);
giving me the error

> data.item is not a function

or

> data.splice is not a function

I'm pretty certain that this is because it is not a true javascript array, but I haven't found anything that has told me how to convert it to one

**EDIT** I was actually looking for the .item() function used in NodeList (from things like getElementByClassName) however, this does not solve my issue with .splice

Comment: `Array.item` isn't a function that exists in Javascript, is it? (Also, your JSON seems to be missing commas.)

Comment: `()` used for executing functions. You need to change that `data[i]`

Comment: What is a "true JavaScript array" and why isn't yours one?

Comment: Before scratching your head over code, you should try to validate your source JSON ... plenty around on the web. Try to cut and paste at http://jsonlint.com for example.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg My bad, I wrote my example wrong

Comment: @Juhana Something like 'new Array()'

Comment: @ODelibalta I forgot to mention that I also need to use .splice, edited in now. I've also been using .item() in most other cases due to being more reliable within embedded functions

Comment: You're using the variable `i` in your question with no explanation why. Where is `i` coming from? It would help if you add all the code (like the loop) to your question.

Comment: @Andy I mentioned it was a linear loop (i++), i's just whatever the current iteration is.

Comment: The problem is that you've not included the actual code for us to look at, just a vague reference to using splice.

Comment: @Andy I literally loop through the length of the array, and take an element out if needed to by my check, which has been tested to work. At this point I'm just looking for a better way to delete an element from an array in such a loop.

Comment: There is no difference between arrays created by `new Array()` or by other means like `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid - it needs commas separating the objects:

```
[{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"},{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"},{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"}]
```

Parse the JSON like you were:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

And to access each object, use the index of the array:

```
var element1 = data[0]; // first element
var element2 = data[1];  // second element
```

etc.

And to access the values in the objects:

```
var name1 = data[0].name1; // value1
```

or even, since you've already defined the `element1` variable:

```
var name1 = element1.name1;
```

If you're using a loop:

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like my example is wrong, woops. Not the actual JSON I was receiving

Answer (score 0):

Once you've run `data = JSON.parse(json)`, you can verify that `data` is an array using either `data instanceof Array` or `Array.isArray(data)`.

In this case, both should be true, because you do have an array. JS arrays simply don't have an `item` method (that is, `Array.prototype` does not have a property `item` that is set to a function, or in fact, an `item` property at all), so you're trying to call something that does not exist.

To access an element from an array, you use the `arr[n]` syntax with a number. This is how you retrieve elements, not calling `item`.

While parsing, if your JSON is invalid, an exception will be thrown. You should wrap the `JSON.parse` call in `try { ... } catch` block to safely handle that.

All together, your code would look something like:

```
try {
  var data =  JSON.parse(json);

  if (data && data.length) { // make sure data is a real thing and has some items
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      console.log(data[i]); // using [] to access the element
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Parsing JSON failed:', e);
}
```

Comment: I need to use .splice also, to remove a certain element (as suggested in other answers), however that is also defined as not being a function